# How do routers handle requests for router/modem configuration webpages?

Tags: networking, router, ip, modem

Something I noticed is that oftentimes it’s possible to connect to the modem through an IP like 192.168.100.1 — however, as [this](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2880475/talk-to-your-modem.html) states:

> So, you might expect a router to detect the internal-use-only IP address, and block it from leaving the WAN port. But, that's not the way they roll (I tested with multiple routers).

This is what I was thinking as well. How does sending a request to 192.168.100.1 cause it to be forwarded to the router’s configuration page? Is that really the IP address of the modem (which I don’t completely understand how it would have its own address on LAN) or is it just a special address that the router knows to forward on to the modem to ask for a configuration page?

Additionally, by making an HTTP request to the public IP (rather than just the internal IP of the router, 10.0.0.1), it will still redirect me to the gateway page. Of course, this page is only available to me as an internal user of the network (i.e. nobody else externally can access it by typing in my IP address)

How is it able to do the above two things? They seem related (maybe DNS) and I can’t figure out what mechanism is causing both these scenarios to work.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here... A router is by definition a router, it really doesn't care if you are using public or private IP address space, if the requested IP address is not within it's LAN or WAN subnet, it is pass it to the next gateway for a routing decision. The configuration web page is at the IP address of the router, or by intercepting DNS for such device like Meraki going to my.meraki.com. For example, my router is 192.168.1.1/24, and my ISP's modem is 192.169.100.1/24, my router just knows because of the subnet mask that it isn't on the lan so it passes the data

Comment: @acejavelin I understand how it works for router configuration but I'm confused about how the modem has an IP and can respond to requests if it doesn't provide NAT or routing services. Say you have a router and a modem that has an ISP-issued IP of `112.B.C.D`. I can log on to `192.168.100.1` to view my *modem*'s configuration and `10.0.0.1` to see my router's configuration. My question is how is it possible to access `192.168.100.1` (modem configuration page) at all? I don't understand how that request gets routed and then intercepted by the modem if the modem just sends down the line.

Comment: It still has to follow the rules of IP routing, and isn't as difficult as it seems... The "gateway" address is actually the modem, and 192.168.100.1 is on a small subnet inside the modem, so when your router hands up a request to the gateway to 192.168.100.1, it's routing table passes to the internal subnet of the modem for configuration purposes instead of passing it to the next routing hop.

Comment: Basically, your "dumb" modem isn't completely dumb... just mostly dumb, except for it's own configuration page/subnet.

Comment: @acejavelin ah, so when you say, "The "gateway" address is actually the modem," could you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router will pass any packets that are not destined for it's LAN out to the next device connected to it's WAN port which is your modem.  For most packets your modem will simply forward these on to your ISP and take no action.

I don't know all the gritty details of how the modem works, but essentially the modem does have an internal network of it's own with it's IP set to 192.168.100.1 along side your ISP's network.  When the modem receives a packet it can check which network to forward that packet too.  If the packet is for the internal network then it'll get sent to the modems internal software which can respond appropriately.  Otherwise the packet goes down the wire to the ISP.

Comment: Does this mean that in a very narrow sense, the modem is also acting as a router? What you described sounds to me like a routing table, where `192.168.100.1/0` is routed to the modem's internal web server (which hosts the configuration web interface), and all else gets forwarded to the default gateway (the ISP)

Comment: @Alexander As mentioned I don't know the details, and they likely vary some from vendor to vendor but essentially yes.  I'm guessing it's using a full 192.168.100.0/24 as mine would dhcp-assign the router something in that range if the cable signal was down.